# Start numbering appendix with arabic, even with just one page?

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I found how to number my appendix using arabic e.g. 'A-1', but it only works when appendix section has multiple pages. If the appendix section only has a single page it still only shows '1' as the page instead of 'A-1'. That only appears once there's more than 1 page. It also shows as just '1' in the table of contents, but I'd rather it be 'A-1'.

Code I'm using:

```
\newpage\begin{appendix}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}

\section{My Appendix On One Page}
\lipsum

\end{appendix}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no explanation for this, but it seems to be solved by moving the new definition outside of the `appendix` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\begin{appendix}

\section{My Appendix On One Page}
\lipsum

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That did seem to work. How odd.